# Wireless network adapter not working

Tags: wireless

I'm new to Linux and I just installed Ubuntu alongside with Windows on dual boot.
Looking at the additional drivers, I don't understand what this think is:
[image: Screenshot]

anybody knows?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your computer to the internet by other means (by wire or USB tethering) and install that DKMS module suggested on your screenshot.

That will install a wireless driver.